# how to fix Speech Synthesis Utterance in javascript

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

When ever i run this code i get a female response and then the second time i get a male voice and if i try to run it again it fails to respond.

here is the code/

```
var aiload = document.getElementById('ai').innerHTML
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(aiload);
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();

voices.forEach(function (voice, i) {
    var voiceName = 'Google UK English Female';
    var selected = '';

    if(voiceName == 'native') {
        selected = 'selected';
    }
    var option = "<option value='" + voiceName + "' " + selected + " >" + voiceName + "</option>";
    voiceSelect.append(option);
    console.log(voiceName);
});

msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
msg.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 10
msg.pitch = 0; //0 to 2
msg.text = aiload;
msg.lang = 'en-US';

msg.onend = function(e) {
    console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
};


speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: re: "_When ever i run this code i get a female response_": man, you should make that snip into a gist...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem seems to be not treating the Web Speech API asynchronously.

The following snippet is not needed for now, but I want to point out that it looks like you never change the `voiceName` variable anywhere so the if statement looks unnecessary:

```
voices.forEach(function (voice, i) {
    var voiceName = 'Google UK English Female';
    var selected = '';

    if(voiceName == 'native') {
        selected = 'selected';
    }
    var option = "<option value='" + voiceName + "' " + selected + " >" + voiceName + "</option>";
    voiceSelect.append(option);
    console.log(voiceName);
});
```

Here's one way you'll get the voice you want every time (notice my changes with comments):

```
var aiload = document.getElementById('ai').innerHTML;

// Use setInterval to keep checking if the voices array has been filled prior to creating the speech utterance
var voiceGetter = setInterval(function() {
  var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  if (voices.length !== 0) {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(aiload);
    // Pick any voice from within the array; you can console.log(voices) to see options
    msg.voice = voices[5];
    msg.volume = 1;
    msg.rate = 1;
    msg.pitch = 0;
    // msg.text = aiload; <== This is redundant because of how msg is defined
    msg.lang = 'en-US';
    msg.onend = function(e) {
        console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
    };
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    clearInterval(voiceGetter);
  }
}, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I know what the problem is. As described in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/onvoiceschanged the list of voices is only available after `speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged` event is fired.

Here is a fiddle to help: https://jsfiddle.net/mx2edhvw/1/

An important thing to notice is that `speak` **adds** an utterance to the system. You need to do a `cancel` before you speak again, else you keep adding more.